# Como esconder a URL do arquivo? (não mostrar ela toda até o arquivo)

Tags: javascript, html

Pessoal quero esconder a URL dos arquivos, exemplo: exemplo.com/cadastro.php
teria alguma forma de deixar só exemplo.com? Ou alguma outra forma, mas que não mostre o caminho completo.
  Obrigado.

Comment: No URL do browser ou nos links no html?

Comment: me parece que ele quer dizer na url do browser @Sergio

Comment: Na URL do browser.

Answer (score 2):

No lado do cliente, com JavaScript isso não é possível a 100%.

Tens duas maneiras que ficam a meio caminho, e que pode servir para o que queres:

- iframes
- re-escrever o url via pushstate

#### [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/iframe)

```
<iframe src="url_a_esconder.php" />
```

assim crias uma página dentro da página para esconder o conteúdo.

#### [pushstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

```
window.history.pushState("", "", '/');
```

assim re-escrevers o url para o dominio

Answer (score 2):

Edite o `.htaccess` e coloque o código abaixo

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .shtml
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

para esconder o .html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

para esconder o .php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: coloquei esses comandos, no .htaccess mas toda vez que a pagina era carregada passou a aparecer a opção pra fazer o download do arquivo, e a url ainda ficou completa.

Comment: Veja se você colocou a versão do seu php corretamente na linha AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
AddHandler exemplo se seu servidor usa a versão 5 o código esta correto se ele a inda usa a versão 4 você deve editar para AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .php
AddHandler

Answer (score 0):

Caso seja no URL do Browser, uma das opções que você pode deixar configurado no seu site é a URL Amigável, e se utiliza .htaccess (para apache) e web.config (para IIS)

**Exemplo de .htaccess**

Exemplo com página simples (Sem $_GET) - No seu caso

```
RewriteRule ^$ ./cadastro.php
```

*De:      /cadastro.php

Para:   / = (url do site)*

Exemplo com página com 1 $_GET

```
RewriteRule ^u/(..*)$ ./u.php?rl=$1
```

*De:      /u.php?rl=CPosmA3gev

Para:   /u/CPosmA3gev*

Exemplo com página com + de 1 $_GET

```
RewriteRule ^pagina-(..*)-(..*)$ ./pagina.php?id=$1&outro=$2
```

*De:      /pagina?id=1&outro=2

Para:   /pagina-1-2*

Não há diferença na formatação da nova url, por isso usei **/** e **-** para mostrar como funciona.

Caso queira um exemplo de .htacces completo, vou deixar um dos meus aqui:
http://pastebin.com/7J4dRVLK

Comment: coloquei isso no .htacces, mas não funcionou:     RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ ./valePontos.php

Comment: Se não for pedir muito será que poderia me ajudar?